# Excel VBA -Copying a range of multiple rows to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, range, rows

```
with Sheets("XYZ")    
wSheet.Range("8:8,9:9,10:10,11:11,12:12,13:13,266:266,472:472").Copy
    .Cells(.Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Select
    .Paste
```

Why does it not work and give me all the rows from 8 to 472 instead?
I need specific rows, not all.

Answer (score 0):

I could get the following code to copy as expected. This was on Excel 2007- it could be that you're on an earlier version that behaves differently.

```
Public Sub Test()
    With Sheets("XYZ")
        .Range("8:8,9:9,10:10,11:11,12:12,13:13,266:266,472:472").Copy
        .Cells(.Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Select
        .Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Mine are indeed different lines of code.
I have updated the code. Pls check

Comment: Thanks Chris, but wSheet is another sheet.